# Place to describe a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

We want to provide a description for our tables, in SQL Server 2005. In looking at the DESIGN tab - I see there a 'Description' is this best place to use for a description, or does this cause any issue?

Comment: What issue would you think adding a description to 'Description' could cause?

Comment: You will do yourself a great favor in the long run if use t-sql to create your objects instead of the UI. You can do this sp_addextendedproperty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the ideal place to put that type of metadata. It will have no adverse effect.

It is stored in Extended Properties, for more information see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186989(v=sql.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you want to write a description you can use the Table "description" property

In the "column properties" you can see that you have a place if you want to add a description for your columns.

---

[image: Table and column properties]